# Send email to author of post on post submission

Tags: posts, author, email

I am using WordPress directory theme. I want to send an email to the author of the post whenever he publishes a new post. Currently, email is just sent to the administrator only. I didn't find any code utilizing `wp_admin` function.

Comment: you need to create a plugin to do this. have you ever made a plugin ? read this : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to tie into the WordPress action `publish_post`. Here is a link to the codex with a basic example:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post

**Note:** If you are looking to do this for a Custom Post Type, you'll need to add an action for `publish_custom_post_type`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tested it, a quick search revealed this (new) plugin which claims to do what you want:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/publish-post-email-notification/

> Publish post notification is plugin which will send automatic email when the post is published and approved by WordPress blog. admin have to go to setting and set email template thats it all other things are managed by this plugin.